# "Failed to inflate" ActionbarSherlock and ViewPager Indicator

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have this app using a ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator and for some reason i keep getting the following error below. I cant seem to figure out why the error is populating. Any help would be greately appreciated. Based on the stack trace i believe its a issue with my main.xml on the line that the viewpager starts, but there is nothing that i havnt done before. Is this maybe coming from the librarys side?

```
 E/ActivityThread(1220): Failed to inflate
 E/ActivityThread(1220): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at      android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:323)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:134)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at com.jaisonbrooks.enlighten.MainActivityViewPager.onCreate(MainActivityViewPager.java:63)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at      java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 /ActivityThread(1220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/ActivityThread(1220): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator" on path: /data/app/com.jaisonbrooks.enlighten-1.apk
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
 E/ActivityThread(1220):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
```

### Code

```
 public class MainActivityViewPager extends SherlockActivity {

private ViewPager awesomePager;
private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 3;
private Context context;
private AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ProgressBar progressBar;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionBar = this
            .getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getSupportActionBar().show();
    context = this;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
    awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    awesomePager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
    TitlePageIndicator awesomeIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
    awesomeIndicator.setViewPager(awesomePager);

}
```

### main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#18FF0000"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textColor="#AA000000"
    app:footerColor="#FFAA2222"
    app:footerIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:footerIndicatorStyle="underline"
    app:footerLineHeight="1dp"
    app:selectedBold="true"
    app:selectedColor="#FF000000" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: This has only been a issue since the latest Support Package update Version 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by the latest update to the `Android Support Library rev.13`, I updated the Support package on my library projects and the own project and since then the issue occurred. Therefore the issue is resolved when using Support package 12 and under.

Answer (score 0):

SherlockFragmentActivity should be used when working with fragments

Comment: I've been using it the following way and its been working just fine. Just started acting up since i transferred my source from my mac to pc.

Comment: I beleive that Sherlock fragment activity works well with support fragment manager

Comment: @alexeiburmistrov Any good example projects, im going to have to convert this entire project over to a fragment based app, which i dont know much about.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock library samples, shipped with the library files contain **extensive** fragment project with almost every possible use of fragments and pager